# How to get OnWindowFocusChanged event call back in fragment from activity in Android?? :O

Tags: android, focus, fragment

I have an fragment activity.Inside that there is a fragment. When i click on a button which is on the activity.one dialog shows up.but when i dismiss the dialog i need to do some UI changes in the fragment. But i am not getting On window focus  change event in fragment. But while dismissing the dialog.the activity is receiving focus change event. How to get focus change event in a fragment? Is there any callback or any interface we can implement.I implemented  on focus change listener in androi but it didnt work.

Comment: None of it worked . :( The view still doesnt get teh focus even if the callback is received. overriding the ethod didnt work. How do we get focus of a fragment whenn an alert dialog is dismissed?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to override [`Activity.onWindowFocusChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) and then dispatch that event to your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` inside Activity and using this pattern [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) pass this event to your fragment . Instead of this communication you also can use some of existing EventBus library (ex. GreenDao EventBus).

Answer (score 0):

Inside **onResume() of Fragment** try using **View.requestFocus()** or in **onResume() of activity** pass the focus to the loaded fragment using requestFocus().

Another way is to override the callback method onWindowFocusChanged() method of activity and handle the fragment accordingly

Comment: There are cases where `onResume()` is not called.  Notification pull-downs, for example.